# How map only one entity with hql

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have this code

```
    Query query = session.createQuery( "FROM EntA a , EntB s "
            + " WHERE a.idSys = b.idSys "
            + "   AND b.flgE  = :est    "
            + "   AND a.idM   = :idm    "
            + "   AND b.dscNC = :ncs    ");

    query.setParameter("idm", idm);
    query.setParameter("est", "A");
    query.setParameter("ncs", avar);
    // Something here????
    query.setMaxResults(1);
    EntA a=(EntA)query.uniqueResult();
```

The query has two entities, but I only wish to obtain one of the entities

Maybe something like:

```
   query.getEntity("a") or query.getAlias("a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
Query query = session.createQuery( "select a FROM EntA a , EntB s "
            + " WHERE a.idSys = b.idSys "
            + "   AND b.flgE  = :est    "
            + "   AND a.idM   = :idm    "
            + "   AND b.dscNC = :ncs    ");
```

if this does not work please provide a reproducer and let me try on my machine :)